# Get rows from primary table, and also a count of how many times that record appears in a secondary table (including 0's)

Tags: sql

I have a Dogs table, a Kennels table and Visits table that contains DogId and KennelId columns.

I am trying to get a full list of all the dogs, with a column showing the number of visits to a particular kennel, so many of the results will contain a 0 as the visit count.

This is what I've tried:

```
select dog.*, visits.visitCount FROM 
(select * from Dogs) as dog, 
(select COUNT (Visits.Id) as visitCount from Visits INNER JOIN Dogs ON Dogs.Id = 
Visits.DogId where KennelId = 'E15A8C60-E0FE-472D-9CC4-08DA251A992F') as visits
```

With this statement, I end up with all of the dogs, but with the same visit count for all, which is incorrect.  I assume my count function is simply executed once with the result repeated for the remaining rows.  I do not know how to correct this.  Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: `dogs CROSS JOIN Kennels`

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: thanks for the comments.  i will try to get better at posting as i go along...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no table schemas or sample data, a guess would be something like the following:

```
select d.*, Coalesce(v.VisitCount,0) VisitCount
from dogs d
left join (
  select DogId, Count(*) VisitCount
  from visits v
  where v.KennedId = 'E15A8C60-E0FE-472D-9CC4-08DA251A992F'
  group by DogId
)v on v.DogId = d.DogId;
```

Comment: That did it, Stu.  Thank you so much.  I never would have figured this out on my own, and will dig in to how this works.

Comment: Stu, this is T-sql, right?  Do you know if there is a standard sql way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: You didn't tag a specific database so this is not dialect specific, it should be ansi compliant with most RDBMS. What is not working for you?

Comment: You are correct.  I should have been more precise in my question.
I don't know that it is not working for me.  I am slowly building a web data system with the help of a developer and want the API to be able to work with any database.  I was under the impression that T-sql functions should be avoided in such an environment.  But I obviously am not certain of that.  We can use what you came up with for now and cross that bridge when we get to it.  Thanks again for your help and insight.

Comment: What makes you think it's t-sql specific? It *could* be made t-sql specific with the use of things like `isnull` and `cross apply`; if your database is SQL Server then there's no reason to avoid anything specific to t-sql unless portability is a requirement, otherwise usiing specific language features is the way to get the best performance out of your hardware and server licensing!

Comment: I should add that trying to write something that is genuinely database agnostic is fraught with issues and really is more trouble than it's worth, things like date and time or string functions will almost always throw a spanner in the works - not to mention some platforms don't even fully support ANSI syntax eg MySql would vomit if you gave it a `full join`...

Comment: These are great insights.  It is an important goal that the final product be able to work with any of the large-scale back ends, but it is not critical right at this moment.  

this web page is what made me think it is T-sql.  I could be misinterpreting it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Coalesce is defined in the ansi / ISO sql standard. I deliberately used `coalesce` above - had you tagged the question as sql server or t-sql I'd have used `isnull` instead, which for two operands is very slightly more performant.